# Conditional category select (TreeView functionality) alternatives.

Tags: website-design

I have a bunch of categories that each has its own subcategory that the user can choose. The user first has to decide upon the main category to be shown the dependent subcategories of the selection. One way to do this is to use tree view, which I am not a huge fan of. I am currently using a 2 column select; it only shows the subcategories after the main category has been selected. Are there any other UX patterns you would suggest for this kind of functionality?

[image]

Comment: Is the user limited to selecting only one child value? Or can they select multiple children values within a parent value? How about across multiple parent values? Also does your hierarchy only go two levels deep max? Or can it go even deeper with sub-sub-categories?

Comment: @mtv.vac there are only 2 hiearchy levels and there are no sub-sub-categories but they may be implemented in the future. They can only pick one option.

Comment: Could you tell us more about it? What are you trying to achieve? I believe this is Slovenian and I guess it refers to some product catalogue.

Comment: @svedr understood-- and does the user have to select a child? Or can they select just a parent level item? If they cannot-- I recommend differentiating the UI between a parent-level item that has been selected for the sole purpose of exposing it's child items, and the selection of the child item itself. I see that you've included a check but think you could go further to clarify the difference.

Comment: Sequential typeaheads? Single list with breadcrumb? Accordion? It would really help to learn more about the context - What is the use case? What's the user flow? Do users choose and commit or do they need to revisit their selection? Also, I'm not a fan of save buttons, but they are the right way to go sometimes. Personal preferences are counter-UX.